# How long does it take for Ramadhan to move from one season into the next?

Tags: time, lunar-calendar

Assalamualaikum and Hello to all,

As a muslim experiencing Ramadhan in Europe, presently in summers, with it's long hours, has led me to think about when I experienced it in winters here when I was a child.

Specifically, I was wondering how long does it take for Ramadhan to move from one season into the next? How long will it be before I experience Ramadhan in winter, after experiencing in summer for some years now?

I will offer some thoughts as an answer, but I'd be grateful for any further thoughts.

Wassalam and best regards.

Comment: You quoted Ramadan,  but what I miss a link to Islam. The matter is a simple calculation and not necessarily related to Islam.

Comment: This question is related to the muslim lunar calendar. Hence in this SE group.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this topic is not about Islam; rather, it is about lunar calendars vs. Gregorian calendars.

Comment: this does not relate to lunar calendar in general (ie any lunar calendar). It relates to the islamic lunar calendar, as clearly stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe one way to address this question could be as follows.

1) The Islamic calendar moves earlier, relative to the gregorian calendar (or backwards in gregorian time), by 10 to 12 days every year.

For instance, in 2017, 1st Ramadhan fell on 28th May. In 2018, this was 11 days earlier on 17th May.

2) Seasons last, on average, 3 months of 30 solar days each, equivalent to 90 solar days.

3) taking 1) and 2) into account, it will take (30days/11days/year) to move across a month, and (30days/11days/year)*3 to move across a season. This will mean **8.18 years** to move across a season.

4) seeing as how this Ramadhan started on 17th May 2018, and that Northern Hemisphere winter ends on 28 feb, (https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/aboutseasons.html) it will take (78days/11days/years), equal to **7.09 years more**, for 1st Ramadhan to enter winter.

Thank you.

Comment: Your last statement is wrong after summer comes autumn not winter.

Comment: The lunar calendar moves earlier every year relative to the Gregorian or solar year. Hence, 'after' 7+ years, Ramadhan will enter winter. After Summer Ramadhans, it will first enter spring, and then winter. The focus of this question, as clearly stated above, is the winter Ramadhan.